# How to code game events in a text-based game in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to create a text-based-like game with a UI (as opposed to a true text-based with parsing and all the fun stuff) that's basically an RPG. To this end, the game has a bunch of different events that could happen (but aren't guaranteed to occur, nor to occur in any overall order), and I'm wondering the most efficient way to code this.

At the moment, my thought is to have a static class called GameState which, among having other information, would have an array and an enum within them. The array would *probably* be bytes for the sake of conversation or multi-optional event choices, where 0 would be that the event hasn't happened, and then a number 1 - X would represent which option out of X possible were chosen.  Something like this:

```
public enum GameEvents{
                       Event 1,
                       Event 2,
                       Event 3 };

public static byte[] GameEventStates = new byte[Enum.GetNames(typeof(GameEvents)).Length];
```

So that in events and stuff, I'd be able to do lines like:

```
if(GameState.GameEventStates[GameState.GameEvents.Event2] == 1)
{
  Stuff Here;
}
```

or

```
GameState.GameEventStates[GameState.GameEvents.Event4] = 1;
```

(Note: for strictly 'Has Seen' events, it'd be 0 for not having seen it and 1 for having seen it).

Part of this just feels forced, though, like there's a more elegant way that I simply can't think of. I don't know what it would be, though, that still allows me to

A) have global access to it for changing values as events happen and allow for checks against their occurances,

B) easily add more events as the content of the game expands over time, and

C) easily save and load the values to/from a save file.

Is this *really* the best way to do this? I'm the first to admit I can come up with... 'creative' ways that aren't really that good for solving problems. A second opinion would really be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: please forgive my ignorance... what exactly is a `text-based-like game with a UI`?

Comment: I'm not great at C# (I'm still learning), but I guess you could make a lot of methods in a separate event class that are named numbers, and call a method based on a random number.

Comment: @HighCore I think he wants to display what happens as text (textbox), but have buttons for actions like "look", "use", ... . So you don't have to type "use key with red door".

Comment: @ProfPickle if you need to call methods randomly based on a random number you could use a `List<Action>`, which is basically a list of methods, then pick a random one using `var theaction = actionList[randomNumber]` indexer syntax.

Comment: @HighCore Basically, the game represents everything as text in a textbox, but every location has a list of options that the player clicks on to select (such as "Go To This Location") instead of typing 'Go North' or something.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a classic example for the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

You need to create class which will hold game state, and if the state changes it will notify all subscribers.

```
public class GameStateManager 
{
 public GameStateFileReader fileReader = new GameStateFileReader() //this class can read gamestate to file, and save it back 

 public void SaveState() {//save using fileReader}
 public void LoadState() {//load}

 public event Action<GameEvents> StateChanged;

}
```

and the Game class can subscribe to StateChanged event:

```
 gameStateManager.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
 //....
 public void OnStateChanged(GameEvents event)
  {
     //react on new game state
  }
```

Some game agents can change game state (user opened the door with some angry boss, for example), so GameStateManager should provide a way to change game state.

```
public void SetNewState (GameEvents newEvent) 
  {
     //Save new state to some Property
     //...

     //and notify everybody about new state
     if(StateChanged != null)
     {
        StateChanged(newEvent);
     }
   }
```

If some class wants to be informed that game state was changed by someone, it should subscribe on this event too.

I didn't want to confuse you with `Action`. You can read about them here:
[Explaining action](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/09/24/explaining-what-action-and-func-are/)

Also, some more info about events:
[Events in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ignore that last comment. I forgot GameEvents was my enum. Ok, This is suddenly making more sense. GameStateManager is a new class that has the Action<> of my GameEvents enum called StateChanged. I also understand that SetNewState passes in a value of the GameEvents (such as Event4 as above), sets the new state, and then sends out the alert about state changed.  ...that middle block of text is confusing me, though. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Text fixed. What do you think about it now?

Comment: ...I think I need to learn more about C#. I can kinda understand what you've got going on here, I think, but a part of me doesn't understand why I need event Action<> (or what it even does) to store the plot checks of a game. Sorry ^^ I'm apparently a little dim... also, what does Do the Rock Here mean? ~.^

Comment: Sorry I've been quiet for so long. RL hit me hard.  Ok, looking at this... I think, if that's how that goes, won't it basically check every time I update ANY state? So even if I say, change a state to say some character died, every subscriber will check their proper set.  Say event 1 is 'Dude A was killed' and event 2 was 'Met Dude B'.  In this way, when I update event 1 from false to true, won't the listener for event 2 also look and go "Ok, you've now met this guy, let's add in his dialog choices on this page"   ...sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: You can have typed events. So you can filter them. Also you can unsubscribe from event if you don't need them anymore. Also you can have different event managers: like LocationEventManager: so when player leaves current location everybody can unsubscribe. Anyway, without knowing all the details I can't give you a good advice. You have a tool now, so It's up to you how to use it. Good luck ;)